# Elasticsearch is returning less relevant results based on insignificant words in the query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I'm building a small web search engine using Elasticsearch. I'm using the following query;

```json
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "title": {
                            "query": "how to format code better golang",
                            "boost": 3,
                            "fuzziness": "AUTO"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "keywords": {
                            "query": "how to format code better golang",
                            "boost": 2,
                            "fuzziness": "AUTO"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "description": {
                            "query": "how to format code better golang",
                            "boost": 1,
                            "fuzziness": "AUTO"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it, these are the first 2 results (they're edited after querying, but the score/position hasn't been tampered with):

```json
{
      "id": "7a8a9b4b96c05460f32d18bba0804fdf",
      "score": 4651,
      "meta": {
        "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IhC7sdYe-Jg",
        "title": "How a Compiler Works in ~1 minute - YouTube",
        "description": "A quick video explaining what a compiler does and how it works. The simple compiler I wrote is available in GitHub: http://www.github.com/charles-l/koona.Red...",
        "keywords": "tutorial, Compiler (Software Genre), compiler, computer, code, language, programming language, clang, gcc, lexer, parser, generator, ruby, how to write a compiler"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "59c42e9f27efc9eea64b25d31d8146d1",
      "score": 4224,
      "meta": {
        "url": "https://dev.to/ksingh7/golang-automatic-code-formatting-code-like-a-pro-205a",
        "title": "Golang automatic code formatting : Code like a Pro - DEV Community",
        "description": "Why Format your code?   Everyone loves clean readable and beautifully organized code using... Tagged with go, formatting, vscode.",
        "keywords": "go, formatting, vscode, software, coding, development, engineering, inclusive, community"
      }
    }
```

Of course, I expect the second result to be more relevant than the first one. But it isn't. I tried a few different queries, but on almost every query I tried, the result that I want to be on the top, is always second or more. Sometimes it did end up on top, but then if I added the word "in" to the query (e.g. "how to format code better **in** golang"), it would become second again.

Is there any way I can make results more relevant?

Comment: did you get a chance to look at my answer?

Answer (score 0):

As you have not shared your index mapping and settings, and mostly using the default analyzer(`standard`) which doesn't remove the english `stop worlds` like `this`, `is`, `how` etc ie insignificant terms in your case. To fix the issue you need to use the `english` analyzer which would remove these terms both at index and query time, and give second document much better score.

Ex:-

POST /my-index

```
{
   "mappings" :{
       "properties" : {
           "title" : {
               "type": "text",
               "analyzer" : "english"
           },
           "description" : {
               "type": "text",
               "analyzer" : "english"
           },
           "keywords" : {
               "type": "text",
               "analyzer" : "english" // note english analyzer on all the fields
           }
       }
   }
}
```

2. Index your both sample docs.
3. Same search produced below result for me.

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "71413449",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 10.55508,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "Golang automatic code formatting : Code like a Pro - DEV Community",
                    "description": "Why Format your code?   Everyone loves clean readable and beautifully organized code using... Tagged with go, formatting, vscode.",
                    "keywords": "go, formatting, vscode, software, coding, development, engineering, inclusive, community"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "71413449",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 5.1878767,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "How a Compiler Works in ~1 minute - YouTube",
                    "description": "A quick video explaining what a compiler does and how it works. The simple compiler I wrote is available in GitHub: http://www.github.com/charles-l/koona.Red...",
                    "keywords": "tutorial, Compiler (Software Genre), compiler, computer, code, language, programming language, clang, gcc, lexer, parser, generator, ruby, how to write a compiler"
                }
            }
        ]
```

**You can notice now your second document score is almost double than your first document**.